# dates ggplot issue

Tags: r, ggplot2

I've started using ggplot recently and I'm a bit confused with the plotting of datetime on the x-axis.

The smallest example with a problem is this:

```
df = data.frame(DateTime=c("2011-03-29 22:44:01", "2011-03-30 00:08:36", "2011-04-07 08:49:50"), response=c(1,2,3))

df$DateTime = as.POSIXct(df$DateTime, format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

This gives ans error:

```
> qplot(DateTime, response, data=df)  
Error in seq.int(r1$year, to$year, by) : 'from' must be finite
```

but this is working fine:

```
>  qplot(DateTime, response, data=df[1:2,])
```

Why is my first plot failing?

As requested sessionInfo() shows:

`sessionInfo()`

> R version 2.12.2 (2011-02-25)
>   Platform: i386-pc-mingw32/i386 (32-bit)
>
> locale:
>   [1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252    >LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C
>   [5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252
>
> attached base packages:
>   [1] grid      grDevices datasets  splines   graphics  stats     tcltk     utils     methods   base
>
> other attached packages:
>   [1] car_2.0-9          nnet_7.3-1         MASS_7.3-11        RColorBrewer_1.0-2  doBy_4.3.0         ggplot2_0.8.9      proto_0.3-9.1      reshape_0.8.4
>   [9] plyr_1.4.1         svSocket_0.9-51    TinnR_1.0.3        R2HTML_2.2         >Hmisc_3.8-3        survival_2.36-5
>
> loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
>   [1] cluster_1.13.3     digest_0.4.2       lattice_0.19-17    Matrix_0.999375-46 >svMisc_0.9-61      tools_2.12.2

And traceback() output:

```
traceback()
20: seq.POSIXt(floor_time(range[1], time), ceiling_time(range[2], 
        time), by = time)
19: fullseq_time(d, .$break_points()[2])
18: get(x, envir = this, inherits = inh)(this, ...)
17: scales$x$output_breaks()
16: inherits(x, "factor")
15: is.factor(x)
14: rescale(data, 0:1, range, clip = clip)
13: get(x, envir = this, inherits = inh)(this, ...)
12: .$rescale_var(scales$x$output_breaks(), x.range, TRUE)
11: get(x, envir = this, inherits = inh)(this, ...)
10: coord$compute_ranges(scales)
9: FUN(1L[[1L]], ...)
8: lapply(seq_along(data), function(i) {
       layer ), 
       scales = , mapping = list(x = DateTime, y = response), 
       options = list(labels = list(x = "DateTime", y = "response")), 
       coordinates = , facet = , plot_env = ))
1: print(list(data = list(DateTime = c(1301431441, 1301436516, 1302158990
   ), response = c(1, 2, 3)), layers = list(), scales = , 
       mapping = list(x = DateTime, y = response), options = list(
           labels = list(x = "DateTime", y = "response")), coordinates = , 
       facet = , plot_env = ))
```

Comment: It works for me. Would you please post your ´sessionInfo()´?

Comment: It works for me too. I am using R 2.12.2 on Mac OS 10.5. As indicated by Iselzer, Posting sessionInfo() would help

Comment: If he is using `ggplot` rather than `ggplot2` then he is way, way out of date.

Comment: I recently had the same problem [(Link to a german Forum)](http://r-statistik.foren-city.de/htopic,2673,TEPCO.html ).
But found no solution to the problem...

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the same problem.  Windows XP / US English / R 2.13.0

I am able to plot up to 476 records, but the error pops up if I have 477 or more.

This works:

```
data=subset(Pressures,DaysAgo<7)[1:476,])
```

This does not:

```
data=subset(Pressures,DaysAgo<7)[1:477,])
```

I'm not sure if it is the number of records or the nature of the 477th record that is causing the problem.

In any case, a **workaround** seems to be to specify the major and minor grid intervals, ie

```
p <- p+scale_x_datetime(major="1 day",minor="6 hours")
```

where p is your plot.

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced the same problem with recent data in my studies.

In fact, changing `df[3,1]` to `2011-04-30 08:49:50` (April 30) makes it work again. Additionally, `plot()` has no problem with this.

So there seems to be some bug in ggplot2 regarding datetime conversions.

**Edit:** I've retested this on my mac and no problems there, so only on Windows. Next step is maybe to check if this is actually a locale issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the issue as well, but for me it is solved since I have updated to R 2.13.1. OP, could you check and confirm this?

```
R version 2.13.1 (2011-07-08)
Platform: x86_64-pc-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] C

attached base packages:
[1] grid      stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] lubridate_0.2.5 ggplot2_0.8.9   proto_0.3-9.2   reshape_0.8.4   reshape2_1.1         xtable_1.5-6    plyr_1.5.2     
[8] zoo_1.6-5      

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] digest_0.5.0    lattice_0.19-30 stringr_0.5     tools_2.13.1
```